# Is it possible to show the "Enter symbol" in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I want to show the symbol for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP). Is there a key combination that displays the symbol?

Comment: How is this on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Windows Key Code    Alt+8626
```

[Downwards_Arrow_With_Tip_Leftwards](http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U21B2/Downwards_Arrow_With_Tip_Leftwards) (decimal 8626 is hexadecimal 21B2)

Comment: I get the symbol ↲ in the browser. But in notepadd++ shows something likethis - ▓ when the characterset is utf-8.

Comment: i got with Alt+8626 ▓ the same thing.

Comment: @Ashwin: perhaps the font you use in Notepad++ isn't able to display this character. The browser can do font substitutions, finding a font able to display a given Unicode character. Notepad++ can use only the specified font (unless your system is able to do such substitution itself).

Comment: The link is broken: *"404. Not Found. The requested URL /unicode/U21B2/Downwards_Arrow_With_Tip_Leftwards was not found on this server."*

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 8 years ago"*

Answer (score 1):

You may mean something like `↲`.

That's [Unicode \u21B2](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8620&number=128) (DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH TIP LEFTWARDS).

Answer (score 0):

**Create custom keyboard layouts**

This means that you can determine how the keys on your keyboard are used and you can optionally switch between multiple keyboard layouts.

For example, you can simply put the copyright symbol on the <kbd>[AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, or change any other key or key combination for yourself. This saves much time for searching in character tables, and it is more comfortable than a lot of code to learn.

For your own keyboard layout, you can be comfortable with the program Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator ([download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)).

Comment: The download link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page.